# Handling Email Does not Exist Error - iOS project using swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, email, firebase

Here's my ResetPassword Button for my iOS application using xcode and swift:

```
//ResetPssword Button
@IBAction func ResetPassword(sender: AnyObject) {

    if validateEmail(EmailTextField.text!) ==  false {
        print("Enter a Valid Email Address")
        let VaildMessage = "Enter an Email Address"
        //Empty TextField Alert Message
        self.disaplayErrorMessage(VaildMessage)
   }

    //Reset
    else {

        ref.resetPasswordForUser(EmailTextField.text) { (ErrorType) -> Void in
            if ErrorType != nil {

                let error = ErrorType
                print("There was an error processing the request \(error.description)")
                let errorMessage:String = "The Email You Entered is not Exist"
                //Error Alert Message
                self.disaplayErrorMessage(errorMessage)

            } else {

                print("Password Reset Sent Successfully")
              if let Email = self.EmailTextField.text {
                let successMessage = "Email Message was Sent to You at \(Email)"

                //Success Alert Message
                    self.disaplayErrorMessage(successMessage) }

            }

    } //reset

    } //Big Else

 } //Button


//Display Alert Message With Confirmation
func disaplayErrorMessage(theMessage:String)
{
    //Display alert message with confirmation.
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: theMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    let OkAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        action in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
    }
    myAlert.addAction(OkAction);
    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


   //Validate Email Function
func validateEmail(candidate: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluateWithObject(candidate)
}
```

I want to make an error that gives the user an alert when email does not exist in the firebase. 
I did not know how to do that. 
What I did, I gave the user an alert when error != nil
Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: It works, but is it the correct way to do the email does not exist error? I mean if error != nil that only means the email does not exist in the firebase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The firebase website has a full listing of error codes

[User Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html)

The pre-defined error codes provide info on pretty much all of the errors you may receive when authenticating or handling users.

```
    ref.resetPassword({
         email: EmailTextField.text!
    }, function(error) {

        if (error != nil) {

            if let errorCode = FAuthenticationError(rawValue: error.code) {
                switch (errorCode) {
                case .UserDoesNotExist:
                    println("Handle invalid user")
                case .InvalidEmail:
                    println("Handle invalid email")
                case .InvalidPassword:
                    println("Handle invalid password")
                default:
                    println("Handle default situation")
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Success!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to FireBase doc [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/resetpassword.html) it may not always be a case. Don't put it as ErrorType, change it to error. It will be NSError type. Check code of the error you get like so:

```
if error != nil {
   if error.description == "INVALID_USER" {
     // show alert that user doesn't exists
   } else {
     // something went wrong
   }
 } 
}
```